# how to stop wso2 to read the file while file is written by other process

Tags: java, linux, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 vfs for file processing from in folder to out folder.A process is writing a file into in folder and wso2 esb process it and move it to out.
The problem is that as a file is created in 'in' folder wso2 starts processing while the file is incomplete.so please suggest the solution to make wso2 start reading file after complete write.
I tried the file locking mechanism using channel lock but its not working in linux.

Answer (score 0):

A VFS proxy in WSO2 ESB will not see a XXX.YYY file as long as there is a XXX.YYY.lock file in the same dir. It works with all OS all protocols (ftp, sftp, ...) : are you able to configure your external process to generate such a lock file ?

An other solution is to configure your external process :

- to use a temp file that is renamed at the end
- or write it in a temp
  folder (on the same filesystem) and move the file to the "in" folder at the end
  ?